# Why textarea is not getting updated in javaFx?

Tags: java, javafx

```
package client;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class HomeController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button btn;

    @FXML
    private TextArea txtarea;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtmsg;
    Socket sock;
    DataInputStream di;
    DataOutputStream dout;

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        try {
            sock = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 8081);
            System.out.println("Client Started....");
            txtarea.setText("Client Started...");

            di = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

            btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                    try {
                        dout.writeUTF(txtmsg.getText().trim());
                        txtmsg.clear();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            Task<Void> t = new Task<Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String msg = di.readUTF().trim();
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    updateMessage("\nServer says : " + msg);
                    txtarea.appendText("\nServer says : " + msg);
                    return null;
                }

            };
            new Thread(t).start();
            // Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(t);


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I m creating chatting application in javaFX...above code is for client..
When server sends some message,it will not appear in client textarea..although message is received in console.

can you provide me some solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the TextArea inside a background thread which is incorrect. You must update it inside `Platform.runLater()`which will force it execute on JavaFX application thread.

Here is a quick demo. Note : I am using a [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) in this example because it is a `reusable Worker`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button btn = new Button("Append");
        TextArea txtarea = new TextArea("Hi ");

        Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                return new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> txtarea.appendText("message "));
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                /*
                 *You can add conditions to check the status of 
                 *the service and execute proper methods.
                 */
                service.restart();
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(txtarea, btn);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks it's working...bt my text area is not getting appended ...any solutions ??

Comment: You can use `Bindings.concat` just as I have shown in my example.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha This doesn't work the second and subsequent times you press the button. Since `txtArea.getText()` returns the current text immediately when you compute the binding, it always concatenates the last message with the original text. (Also, since updates to message are coalesced, you're not guaranteed to see every message this way.) You need to use a `Platform.runLater()` here.